# Scroll 100% height of the block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

How can I get my Avada (or Custom Wordpress Theme) scroll 100% height divs to go full height of the browser when I have to scroll down or up?

Thank you in advance

[Live example](http://pollenlondon.com/playing-fashion/)

Comment: Using JQuery. You can use this script - http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

**1º** - With CSS, using Viewport Units (vw,vh)

```
section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

section.one {
  background: red;
}

section.two {
  background: grey;
}

section.three {
  background: blue;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/216/)**

**2º** - With JQuery using fullpage.js script

**[DEMO](http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)**